# Merging 2 regex's that allows only english and arabic characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I got 2 regex,

`^((([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}\s{0,1}){1,})$` => this is for english alphabet only

`^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]*$` => this is for arabic alphabet only

I want to or them together tried `|` operator but no chance.
Can you help me?

Comment: So how did you try? What was wrong with that attempt? Show it. Explain what you expect. A lot of people "join" patterns using `" | "` without understanding that spaces matter.

Comment: `tried | operator` how exacty? Remeber that `$` marks the end of a string so you have to omit that on your first regex as well as the `^` on your second regex

Comment: `^((([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}\s{0,1}){1,})|[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]*$` like this. I just want true if characters only english or arabic, false if number or special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `|` operator, but each individual regex will need to be enclosed by parentheses. You can also use `?:` at the beginning of the parentheses to signify that you don't want that pattern [captured in a group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups).

```
(?:^((([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}\s{0,1}){1,})$)|(?:^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]*$)
```

Comment: `^(((([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}\s{0,1}){1,})|[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF])*$` thank you i did this and it worked